# Is this question a good fit for this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I have a question about a teenager friend who is greatly affected by the feelings of love he bears for a girl.She doesn't feel the same and this upsets him.

You may say that this is a common story and he will most likely get over this,but that's not true.This thing has been present in his life for 6 years.And the worrying part is that this entire situation has taken a toll on his health,too.He constantly complains that he feels pain in different regions of the body.He received treatment for ill kidneys.Continuing on this,he is always sad and can't do his student work.His parents seem to be neglecting him.A doctor told me that if he continues like this,he can receive serious mental damage,like schizophrenia.I am his friend and I want to help him,but I don't know how.He has to forget that girl and carry on with his life.I spoke to him many times about this,but it doesn't work.

What can I do to end this?How can I help him?

This is the body of the question.Do you think it is a good fit for the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a good fit at all. In fact, it would be off topic because you're asking for a diagnosis and treatment for your friend. The site does not offer personal medical advice so if you ask, your question is likely to be downvoted and closed.

Is it psychological or physical? We have no way of knowing. You say he's been treated for some sort of kidney disorder and complains of pain. Clearly, he needs to see a medical doctor first to have physical problems ruled out before anything else.

As for being upset about a girl causing schizophrenia, that's utter rubbish. Schizophrenia isn't caused by stress.

The better question would be does he already have a mental illness? It sounds like his fixation on this girl is a bit over the top, and for that an assessment by a psychologist might be a good idea once physical problems have been ruled out.